# TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable when starting django runserver

Tags: python, django, django-urls

When I try to run server, I get this following error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 325, in check
warnings = self._check_pattern_name()
File "/Users/josephshenouda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 333, in _check_pattern_name
if self.pattern.name is not None and ":" in self.pattern.name:
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [

path('explore/', views.explore, name='explore'),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='profile'),
#path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.view_profile, name='profile_with_pk'),
path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='profile-edit'),
path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change-password'),
path('reset-password/', PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='accounts/reset_password.html',
    success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')),
    name='reset-password'),
path('reset-password/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset-password/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
 ]
```

home/urls.py:

```
app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [

path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name=change_friends)


]
```

main/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
 path('home/', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

EDIT: I've now uploaded the urls in my project. Thanks again. Im writing this text as my post is mostly code. Ive tried editing urls but that doesn't work so just looking for the solution.

I never had any problems before, I'm wondering if I accidentally changed something. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be an error in `urls.py`. Please show its code

Comment: hi ive added urls

Comment: Where is `static` imported from in `main/urls.py`?

Comment: from django.conf.urls.static import static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I found the error

```
re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name=change_friends)
```

The name must be a string so it shoud be like this

```
re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
```

Comment: Just spent 15 mins looking for this. Thank you hahah

Comment: Small mistake but took a while to found. thanks!